# What's required for Python Click script to access it's own module directory?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

How do I use a Python Click script anywhere in my home directory, and have my script access configs inside the the module's directory?

Let's say I have a little scriptie called `ClickDir` and it resides in my home directory `~/bin`. Here's the tree for a simple script:

```
.
├── ClickDir
│   ├── config
│   │   └── helloworld_input.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── scripts
│       ├── clickscript.py
│       └──  __init__.py
├── HelloWorld_output.txt
└── setup.py
```

It's a very useless script. It reads a file in `config` and concatenates this text with an input text file of your choosing. Finally, it writes `HelloWorld_output.txt` to the same directory as your INPUT file,

`Usage: ClickDir [OPTIONS] INPUT`

I can call the Click function from anywhere, but Click also looks relative to that directory for `config/helloworld_input.txt`. And so, the script fails to find the config input,

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../config/helloworld_input.txt'
```

I need to apply this in both Linux and Windows (Anaconda on Win 10)

UPDATE:

```
import click
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("config/helloworld_input"))

#@cli.command()
@click.command()
@click.argument('input', type=click.File('rb'))
@click.option('--saveas', default='HelloWorld.txt', type=click.File('wb'))
def inout(input, saveas):
    with open(dir_path + "/helloworld_input") as conf:
        print(conf.read())
    while True:
        chunk = input.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        saveas.write(chunk)
```

My script is located here:
`/home/xtian/Documents.x/Projects/CliTools.d/ClickDir/scripts`

I backed up a few directories, and ran the script from Projects, but unfortunately the solution described below just calls from the call directory--same as before:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/xtian/Documents.x/Projects/config/helloworld_input'`

Comment: You need to show the code in `clickscript.py`. Also, what does this have to do with Anaconda? I removed the Anaconda tag, but please add it back if there is some connection I missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__file__` pseudo variable, to find the directory where your script is located.

`dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Then you can use `os.path.join` to compose full paths of your data files

Comment: line 3 should be

`dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: also first function in the method should be

`with open(os.path.join(dir_path, "helloworld_input")) as conf`

Comment: Helps if I understand how to use it. (>_<) I've never run into this idiom before with `__file__` psudo--what's that called? Works like a function or what? Callback? And finally, Woot! works both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: It's a variable, but it is different in module file.  It's value is a full path of the filename where the module was loaded from.  You need to use realpath to handle some weird cases.  I am not sure what it is set to if you loaded not from the file,  but from inside of 'egg' or some other weird space.  In your case it will be always set correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a absolute path instead of the relative path to the file. For example: `~/bin/ClickDir/config/helloworld_input.txt`